# how to customize id for collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails4 and bootstrap_form.

When I write

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :helpability, People.all_helps, :id, :name
```

the html is like

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="people_helpability_resume">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    value="resume"
    name="people[helpability][]"
    id="people_helpability_resume" />
    RESUME
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="people_helpability_interview">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    value="interview"
    name="people[helpability][]"
    id="people_helpability_interview" />
    INTERVIEW
  </label>
</div>
```

Is there a way to customize id to something like `helps_resume`, `helps_interview`, where "resume" and "interview" is in People.all_helps?

Also what is the argument `:id` for? How can I use this value method?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No. I put the comment in the stackoverflow conversation. I thought you saw it.

Comment: I've asked for your code, I don't have idea what you're trying.

Comment: My response is here. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159894/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-makeapp I thought you received the notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) is defined as:

```
collection_check_boxes(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

So you can add specify the options argument as an empty hash, and then add any html option, like id in your case. So this should work (should):

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :helpability, People.all_helps, :id, :name, {}, id: 'helps_resume'
```

You need to open a block, print the label, corresponding to the block, inside the label open a block again and print the input, being there you can edit the html options as needed:

```
= form.collection_check_boxes :helpability, People.all_helps, :id, :name do |block| 
  = block.label { block.check_box id: "#{block.object.name}-id" } 
  = block.label { block.object.name }
```

For further info you can inspect `block`.

Comment: Do you mean to change the input value attribute? that corresponds to the `:name` key you're passing as argument, it comes from the data stored.

Comment: No. So currently id is "people_helpability_resume" and "people_helpability_interview". I want them to be "helps_resume" and "helps_interview".

Comment: Adding the id as the last argument should work in that case.

Comment: How? I want to multiple different id values.

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't work. Value of id is not changed. It is still people_helpability_interview and people_helpability_resume.